# How to write select-where-column=unique query in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, distinct

I'm unable to write select-where-unique query for my database. I have managed to query my db using where clause by using:

```
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                        KEY_ROWID,
                        KEY_KEYWORD}, 
                        KEY_TIME + "=" + strtime, 
                        null,
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null);
```

How can I insert "DISTINCT" keyword for column KEY_KEYWORD?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following worked for me:

```
                Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                        KEY_KEYWORD}, 
                        KEY_TIME + "=" + strtime, 
                        null,
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null, 
                        null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
```

Thanx Desiderio and lucho for trying to help.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
Cursor mCursor = 
                db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { 
                        KEY_ROWID, 
                        KEY_KEYWORD},  
                        null,  
                        null, 
                        KEY_KEYWORD,  
                        null,  
                        null,  
                        null);
```

and let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks! This worked. You should use DISTINCT if you want to have the whole row unique, but GroupBy when just one column.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution to your problem is to use the class SQLiteQueryBuilder.

Example:

Query: SELECT DISTINCT A.x FROM A,B WHERE A.ID = B.ID

```
SQLiteQueryBuilder sqLiteQueryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
sqLiteQueryBuilder.setTables("A, B");
sqLiteQueryBuilder.setDistinct(true);

String selection =  "A.ID = B.ID"; 

Cursor c = sqLiteQueryBuilder.query(db, 
    new String[]{"A.x"}, 
    selection, 
    null, 
    null, 
    null, 
    null);
```

Cheers!